# Accessing pointers using objects

Tags: c++, pointers, object, linked-list

I'm writing a program in which i intend to make three DIFFERENT singly linked lists but all sharing the same ADT for the node of the linked list.

```
    class node
    {
     int data;
     node* next;
     }*start;
```

So my query here is if i want to access the data pointed to by the start pointer of the first linked list, how do i do that ? if i create say 3 objects (obj1,obj2,obj3) of class node corresponding to three different linked lists then will the statement

```
    obj1.start->data
```

be a valid way to access the data in the node pointed to by the start pointer of the first linked list

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a struct node inside a class XYZ as follows:

```
class XYZ {
  struct node {
    int data;
    node *next;
  }*start;
}
```

Then for 3 different linked lists with the same node structure, create 3 objects obj1, obj2 and obj3 of type XYZ.
Then access the data using:

```
obj1.start->data
obj2.start->data
```

and so on.

`obj1.element` refers to the variable named 'element' of the object 'obj1'. The start node is a variable inside the class named XYZ, so you can refer to it by creating an object of that class XYZ, and writing `obj1.start`

Your code does not work because in it, start is a pointer OF TYPE node, but what we want is a pointer INSIDE the class for `obj1.start` to work.